# How to test this with RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Using RSpec, I want to test that certain methods are called within a method. Take the following example class:

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
    def process
      case self.file_name
      when /\.html$/
        to_pdf
      end
    end
end
```

How would I test that `to_pdf` is called when `process` is called on an Upload instance with file_name = 'foo.html'? I'd like to do this using a test double if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
instance = Upload.new
instance.file_name = "foo.html"

instance.should_receive(:to_pdf)

instance.process
```

Comment: Thanks! I was doing the same thing but using a test double instead and was getting some errors I couldn't figure out how to fix.